# Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.commit is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vue method that wants to commit data to a vuex mutation, for some reason  I keep getting *Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.commit is not a function*

The error triggers when I click the list item and call the function.

---

sample.vue

```
<li class="tabs-title" v-for="item in filteredItems" v-on:click="upComponents" :key="item.initials" >

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      const coins = this.$store.state.coin.coin;
      if (!this.search) return coins;

      const searchValue = this.search.toLowerCase();
      const filter = coin => coin.initials.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
          coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);

      return coins.filter(filter);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    upComponents(item) {
      this.$store.commit('updatedComp', item);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.tabs = new Foundation.Tabs($('#exchange-tabs'), {
      matchHeight: false,
    });
  },
  destroyed() {
     this.tabs.destroy();
  },
};
```

This is the store.js file where I declare the mutation.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import coin from '../data/system.json';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default {
  state: {
   coin,
   selectedCoin: 'jgjhg',
  },
  mutations: {
    updatedComp(state, newID) {
     state.selectedCoin.push(newID);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    coin: state => state.coin,
  },
};
```

main.js, this is where I declare the Vue app

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import store from './store/store';


window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = jQuery;

require('motion-ui');
require('what-input');
require('foundation-sites');


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
});
```

This is the page I'm working on, where I load all the components:

```
<template>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div >
       <headline-exchange></headline-exchange>
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
import Headline from './molecules/Headline';

export default {
  components: {
   'headline-exchange': Headline,
  },
};

</script>
```

Comment: Are you using a module system? If so, have you added `Vuex` as a plugin, ie `Vue.use(Vuex)`? See https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/installation.html

Comment: in the store.js, yes.

Comment: Have you injected the `store` into the root `Vue` instance, eg `new Vue({ ..., store, ...})`? See https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components

Comment: yes, and I can retrieve data from the store

Comment: Please add more code! Full code in your component pls.

Comment: i'm working with templates, not with components, if it helps finding a solution

Comment: I think you're going to have to show some more of your component then. How are you creating each component instance? Also show how you're injecting your "store" into the root `Vue` instance

Comment: The error triggers when I click the list item and call the function.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I'm working with templates, not with components"*? `sample.vue` *appears* to be a component (albeit without the `<template>` and `<script>` elements shown). Also, you haven't answered my questions about the root `Vue` instance and how you're creating instances of your component (or template or whatever it is)

Comment: i wanted to say with templates not with multiple modules in one page

Comment: you mean index.js? I use routes, or the code I just updated at the bottom?

Comment: i updated at the bottom what I think you're talking about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are **not** creating a `Vuex` store. All you have is an object defining the store properties.

Change your `store.js` to be

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... }, 
  // etc
})
```

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

Comment: that officially solved the question I asked even tough now i got another similar one :) Uncaught TypeError: state.selectedCoin.push is not a function

Comment: @lopezi that's an easy one, `selectedCoin` is a string, not an array