# Recurring this.$store.commit is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using vue.js for the first time and I'm having an issue I've researched but not gotten to the bottom of yet. For advice so far, I've found these articles:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuex-anybody-typeerror-thisstorecommit-is-not-a-function?page=1

[Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.commit is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416012/uncaught-typeerror-this-store-commit-is-not-a-function)

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-this-store-commit-is-not-a-function/31001

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk_I-AhejbAhWPv1MKHRjMAyEQFghtMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Falligator.io%2Fvuejs%2Fintro-to-vuex%2F&usg=AOvVaw2Pimf2n5yvOU5NpRsaCfCz

I have this store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

const state = {
  loggedIn: false
}

const mutations = {
  truthify: state => state.loggedIn = true
}

const getters = {
  loggedIn: state = state.loggedIn
}

const store = new Vuex.Store {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}

export default store;
```

Pointing to this component:

```
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <div id="loginMain">
    <form>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username"></input>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password"></input>
      {{ loggedIn }}
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="post-form" @click="testLogin"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState, vuex } from 'vuex'
import store from '@/store/'

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data: function() {
      return {
        loggedIn: ''
      }
  },
  computed: {
    returnMessage: function() {
      return this.$store.state.loggedIn
    }

  },
  methods: {
    testLogin(){
      console.log('foo');
      this.$store.commit('truthify');
    }
  },
  store: store,
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: check [Vuex Guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), it seems you didn't follow this `Vuex provides a mechanism to "inject" the store into all child components from the root component with the store option` like `const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store})`

Comment: So actually I did have that part previously, but kept getting a 'store is not defined' error in DevTools, so I kept dismantling and re-writing the code. I'm going to post an update to include the behavior with that edit.